# after showing splash screen my app shows only blank white page not my webpage

Tags: android, splash-screen

When I open my app its shows my splash screen and after that it show blank white screen inset of my webpage. Please help me to get it fix guys, I will post all the code if anyone need to know

**when i try this code it will open the after splash screen page**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/");
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //hide loading image
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //show webview
        findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }});
```

**but when i try to make it (open external link in browser only) then after splash screen the next page not coming and showing blank screen**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/");
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!url.startsWith("http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**here is my full MainActivity.java**

```
package club.moviestreet.www.moviestreet;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Convert Website to Android Application");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Vist www.AndroidWebViewApp.com if you Want to Convert your Website or Blog to Android Application");
        return intent;
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have not told what should happen instead. Is there anything you try to display? Then why dont you tell? How would we know?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to know

Comment: Well what should the user of your app see instead? And why?

Comment: i try to make webview of my page

Comment: please also post yourr mainActivity.mxl

Comment: now i update the post plz check

Comment: whats your device android version?

Comment: android 5.1 sir

Comment: i tested your code and it works fine. what do u want to do exactly?

Comment: it keeps opening in webview and what I want is that the links do not belong to my website open in my default browser(like other website download link etc). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this. after yourWebsite loads, if you click on any links, shouldOverrideUrlLoading will be triggered :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!url.startsWith("http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/")) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: mWebView.setWebViewClient(). just replace that and the rest will work

Comment: thanks sir its work now, but sir one more thing when new page load its not showing loading icon on middle center position

Comment: override onPageStarted() method in webViewClient and set visibility of your indicator VISIBLE there

Comment: can you give me the code sir and where to replace the code plz

Answer (score -1):

just solved it now paste this code

```
//Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

after  this

```
//show webview

    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```